# How to Fix My Placeholder Not Showing In Form Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

i want to add `placeholder` in my input. But i'm using `form_helper` from `Codeigniter`.

When i'm added, the `placeholder` not showing up in my input form.

Where the fault it is, in My code or another somethings else?

I'm using a framework `Codeigniter` with `Bootstrap`

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('subscode');?> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="code" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Code:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <?php echo form_input('inputcode','','class=form-control','','placeholder=Input your code..');?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the input attributes as array, like this :

```php
<?php echo form_open_multipart('subscode');?> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="code" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Code:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php echo form_input('inputcode','', ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Input your code..']);?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But, if i want to add onclick javascript. like ['onClick'=>'validation()'] too?

Comment: Correct, put every custom attribute you need into the array, the format is : `form_input('name', 'value', [ /*any additional attributes here*/ ])`

Comment: Okay, i will try. Thanks for help hehe :D

Answer (score 1):

add "" in the placeholder

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('subscode');?> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="code" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Code:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <?php echo form_input('inputcode','','class="form-control"','','placeholder="Input your code.."');?>
                    </div>
                </div>...
?>
```

or add in array:

```
$data = array(
              'name'        => 'inputcode',
              'id'          => 'inputcodeid',
              'value'       => 'test value',
              'placeholder'   => 'placeholder here',
  );

echo form_input($data);
```

Comment: thanks, the code succesfull but i use the sortly code :D

Answer (score 1):

Can you pass an associative array containing data you wish your form to contain? like

```
<?php 
   $data = array(
    'name'          => 'inputcode',
    'class'         => 'form-control',
    'placeholder'     => 'put your placeholder',
    'size'          => '50', //if necessary
    'style'         => 'width:50%' //if necessary
   );
   echo form_input($data);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, the code succesfull but i use the sortly code :D